# How to Access PXSelectorAttribute Joined Table

Tags: acumatica

Is it possible to get a joined table from the PXSelectorAttribute on a field?  For instance, if I have the selector defined as below for selecting a customer joined with the contacts for the customer:

```
 [PXSelector(typeof(Search2<BAccountR.bAccountID, InnerJoin<Contact, 
  On<BAccountR.bAccountID, Equal<Contact.bAccountID>>>>),
  SubstituteKey = typeof(BAccountR.acctCD))]
```

How can I get the Contact record that is joined to the customer that the user selected?

I've tried using the various methods on the PXSelectorAttribute.* but, nothing seems to work.

I also tried setting up Projection to do the join but, that's not working either.  The projection table is not being returned by any of the PXSelectorAttribute.* methods.

TIA!

Comment: Just trying to understand what you are asking for, do you want a selector that lets you search and select a customer, and once a customer is chosen, the selector displays/stores a linked Contact? assuming the Default contact?

Comment: Not exactly.  I want the user to be able to search by contact but, they are technically still selecting a customer.  Then, I want to be able to get the Contact record on the field updated event.

Comment: The question is a little confusing. Are you wanting to add Contact fields to the selector so then you can search on them? if so the selector allows for passing the set of fields you want to display if providing a custom set of columns for the selector.  If then the search still doesn't return the results to the column you want, I think there is a fast filter field option on the page on that field you can set for searchable columns but not sure if that is still required.

Comment: I'm sorry, I'm not sure how to explain it any clearer.  Yes, I want to search by contacti fields.  I have accomplished that with the PXSelector that I included in the post where the Contact Records are inner joined to the Customer record.  What I need to know is how to get the Contact record that was inner joined to the customer record that the user selected.  So, if a Customer has 5 contacts, the user will see the contact information along with the customer information in the selector - how can I get the Contact record after they make their selection?  Thanks for your input!